# Convert many static arrays with same size to dynamic allocation in C

Tags: c, arrays, static, dynamic-allocation

We have a program in C with many (couple hundreds) static arrays defined with same size like:

```
int Array_1[ARRAY_SIZE];
my_struct_t Array_2[ARRAY_SIZE];
char Array_3[ARRAY_SIZE];
his_struct_t Array_4[ARRAY_SIZE];
.....
.....
```

With the scaled development, I need to increase the ARRAY_SIZE accordingly.  However, to avoid wasting more memory and bump up the ARRAY_SIZE manually time by time, I decide to convert all relevant static array to dynamic allocation (linked list).   So every time when I need to access a static array, I will look for its pointer and allocate new memory as needed.

Instead of manually remove all static arrays and convert to dynamic allocation, is there any better and smarter way to do this in a generic method?

What I have in mind is to have a function like `get_element(void *head_ptr, size_t struct_size, int idx)` to get a relevant element based on the header pointer and struct size.   Any thought?

Comment: You probably want to do it in c++, so it would be nice if you add c++ tag to the question :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding!  Actually it is in C.   :(  Added the tag and edited the title.